# Record select option values line after line. HTML/JS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to record each value as a row of text in a central file every time the button is clicked 
showing the value of `'var text ='` row by row.

When I say central file I am open to any suggestions, a lightweight DB or what ever would be a simple solution. This is only to keep a log of each time the tool was used and to keep a log of what was selected. Just something quick and simple for auditing my tool.

**HTML**

```
<script src="jquery-git.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<select name="option" id="option_id">
<option value="1">[No number listed]</option>
<option value="2">[Not answered]</option>
<option value="3">[Answered – not oncall – assisted with issue]</option>
<option value="4">[Answered – not oncall – unavailable]</option>
<option value="5">[Answered – oncall - unavailable]</option>
<option value="6">[Answered – oncall - available]</option>
</select>


<button name="Log" type="submit" id="Log-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Log</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Log-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(e.target);
        btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
    var url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    var text = $("#option_id option:selected").text(); //Payload
    console.log(text);
    $.ajax({
      data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
        "text": text
      }),
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: url
    });
  });
});
```

**Example file - after 10 recorded values**

```
[Answered – not oncall – assisted with issue]
[Answered – not oncall – assisted with issue]
[Answered – not oncall – unavailable]
[Answered – oncall - available]
[Answered – oncall - available]
[Answered – not oncall – assisted with issue]
[Answered – not oncall – assisted with issue]
[Answered – not oncall – unavailable]
[Answered – not oncall – unavailable]
[Answered – not oncall – unavailable]
```

Comment: Persistent for one user or for all?

Comment: All users if possible, but they will have access to any shared file location